# RecyclerView Not Scrolling in NavigationView

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

I have two recyclerviews inside of a drawerlayout navigationview that slides in from the right. The one that scrolls horizontally on the top works, although you have to hold somewhere else first so the thing doesn't think you're trying to slide the view back over. The bigger issue, though, is that the second recycler view for messages does not let you scroll. I tried removing all the extra attributes like clickable and transcriptmode and tried moving that recycler view to the bottom of the XML and neither worked. Here is my main page XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_user_marker_details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.test.test.User_Marker_Details"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/userMarkerToolbar"
            style="@style/HeaderBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#279d43"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:transitionName="actionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay"
            app:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay"
            app:title="Go Back"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/topRL"
            android:layout_below="@id/userMarkerToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:text="00"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:id="@+id/textViewUserMarkerDetCount"
                android:textSize="60sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/peopleInHerdLinearLayout"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewUserMarkerDetCount"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textViewUserMarkerDetCount"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:text="people"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="in the herd"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/peopleInHerdLinearLayout"
                android:text="Outdoor Activity"
                android:lines="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                android:id="@+id/categoryTextView"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/peopleInHerdLinearLayout"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/notifyHerdButtonBackground"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/categoryTextView"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_background_green"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/notifyHerdButton"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/cow"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/notifyHerdButtonBackground"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/notifyHerdButtonBackground"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/notifyHerdButtonBackground"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_below="@id/topRL"
            android:text="people who joined the herd..."
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="normal|italic"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <ListView
            android:layout_below="@id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/myUserCheckedInListView" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/herdchatButton"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/herdchat_button"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_chat"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/topRL"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="5dp"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/herdchatSlideInView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp">

        <include layout="@layout/activity_herdchat"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

XML that is included in the above, which has the recyclerview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_user__subscriptions"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.test.test.HerdchatActivity"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:id="@+id/herdchatHerdsRecyclerView"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:listitem="@layout/herdchat_herds"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/separatorView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/logoGreen"
        android:layout_below="@id/herdchatHerdsRecyclerView"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/messagesRecylcerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/separatorView"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
        android:layout_above="@+id/divider"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        tools:listitem="@layout/chat_message_left"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/logoGreen"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relSendMessage" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relSendMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">


        <EditText
            android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
            android:id="@+id/messageBodyField"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="@color/logoGreen"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnSend"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnSend"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnSend"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnSend"
            android:inputType="text"
            tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSend"
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="Send"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@color/logoGreen"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Changing to the below allows it to scroll, but now when scrolling up at any speed other than really slow, will make the navigationview close, if anyone knows a way to fix that too, like disable slide in when the recyclerview is being touched?:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/herdchatHerdsNestedSV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/herdchatHerdsRecyclerView"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:listitem="@layout/herdchat_herds"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/separatorView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/logoGreen"
        android:layout_below="@id/herdchatHerdsNestedSV"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/messagesNestedSV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/separatorView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/messagesRecylcerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:stackFromBottom="true"
            tools:listitem="@layout/chat_message_left"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Also, the alwaysScroll does not work anymore, so I'm trying this, which is semi-working, I just need to play with it some more I think, unless anyone knows a better way:

```
    mMessagesNestedSV.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

Comment: try putting nested scroll around too

Comment: did you try nested scrolling enabled attribute of recycler view?

Comment: If you're not using `NavigationView` for its specific functionalities – i.e., the built-in menu, header support, etc. – then just get rid of it. The `RelativeLayout` itself can act as the drawer. It doesn't have to be a `NavigationView`. Just make sure the appropriate `layout_gravity` attribute is whatever you're using as the drawer. Also, `NavigationView` wasn't really meant to have arbitrary `View`s added to it. It has specific functionalities, and it builds its own internal structure.

Comment: very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick for you man in order to have more amount of scrollers in a single view you are bound to have nested scroll as your root element or at least parent of all the Scrolling ones.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NestedScrollView     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/activity_user__subscriptions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.test.test.HerdchatActivity"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:id="@+id/herdchatHerdsRecyclerView"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:listitem="@layout/herdchat_herds"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/separatorView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/logoGreen"
            android:layout_below="@id/herdchatHerdsRecyclerView"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/messagesRecylcerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/separatorView"
            android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
            android:layout_above="@+id/divider"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:stackFromBottom="true"
            tools:listitem="@layout/chat_message_left"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/logoGreen"
            android:layout_above="@+id/relSendMessage" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relSendMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            android:paddingEnd="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">


            <EditText
                android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
                android:id="@+id/messageBodyField"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@color/logoGreen"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnSend"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnSend"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnSend"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnSend"
                android:inputType="text"
                tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSend"
                android:layout_width="72dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="Send"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:background="@color/logoGreen"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</NestedScrollView?
```

Comment: The formatting I had to change around, see my update, but nestedscroll did help, thanks!